# Case when in variable declaration

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I'm looking for another column that will give the overall total counts from each gender next to the `eduCounts` column.  The rest of the query works fine.  Finding the distinct gender counts in this case has to be done by `select count(distinct patid) from...`

first try:

```
declare @sexcounts int
set @sexcounts = case when members.sex 'm' then (select COUNT(distinct patid) from members where sex='m')
                 when members.sex 'f' then (select COUNT(distinct patid) from members where sex='f')

select sex, edutext, COUNT(*) as eduCounts from 
(
select distinct m.patid, m.sex, e.eduText
    from members as m
    inner join claims as c on c.patid=m.PATID
    inner join icdClm as ic on ic.clmid=c.clmid
    inner join tblICD as t on t.ICD=ic.icd
    inner join EducationTable as e on e.eduID=m.education
    inner join IncomeTable as i on i.incomeID=m.income
    where ISNUMERIC(ic.icd)=1 and SUBSTRING(ic.icd,1,3)='707'
)t
group by sex, eduText
order by sex
```

second try:

```
declare @sexcounts int
set @sexcounts = (select COUNT(distinct patid),case when sex 'm' then (select COUNT(distinct PATID) from members where sex='m') else (select COUNT(distinct patid) from members where sex='f') 
                    from members)

    select sex, edutext, COUNT(*) as eduCounts from 
    (
    select distinct m.patid, m.sex, e.eduText
        from members as m
        inner join claims as c on c.patid=m.PATID
        inner join icdClm as ic on ic.clmid=c.clmid
        inner join tblICD as t on t.ICD=ic.icd
        inner join EducationTable as e on e.eduID=m.education
        inner join IncomeTable as i on i.incomeID=m.income
        where ISNUMERIC(ic.icd)=1 and SUBSTRING(ic.icd,1,3)='707'
    )t
    group by sex, eduText
    order by sex
```

I know I could make a derived table and join on the sex column, but I'd like to know how to do it with a variable if at all possible.

Comment: does the first and second query gives you the result like in the image you have shown us but it lacks the fourth column, `overall total counts`?

Comment: correct.  they both give the same data as what i posted, it was just a different try at getting the case when statement in a variable declaration right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
select Sex, eduText, eduCounts, sum(eduCounts) over (Partition by Sex) from(
select Sex, eduText, count(eduText) eduCounts
From TableName group by Sex, eduText)x
```